# Why is my php script not getting what it needs to from the database?

Tags: php, mysql, get, phpmyadmin

Im am able to get data from the database but when I go to grab something, in this case its all users, and print it to the screen it shows nothing as if somewhere along the way it went off track and nothing got put in there. I included all files and classes that I think are necessary. Thanks in advance.

```
//showUsers.php
// Displays a list of all users 
// Input: an array of CommentData objects
<?php
function showUsers($userList, $msg) {
    echo "<h1>".$msg."</h1>";

    foreach ($userList as $user) {
        $user->printUser();
        //echo $user;
    }

    echo '<h3><a href="../index.php">Back to home</a>';
}
?>




//usersController.php
<?php
include_once("../views/showUsers.php");
include_once("../models/UserDB.class.php");
include_once("../models/UserData.class.php");
include_once("../models/Database.class.php");

$myUsers = UserDB::getAll();
showUsers($myUsers, "All users");
?>



//UserData.class.php
// Responsibility: Holds data for comment and performs validation
// Constructor expects an associative array with field values for initialization
<?php
class UserData {
    private $userId;
    private $user;
    private $userFirstName;
    private $userLastName;


    public function __construct($formInput) {
        $this->initialize($formInput);
    }

    public function getUser() {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function getUserFirstName(){
        return $this->userFirstName;
    }

    public function getUserLastName(){
        return $this->userLastName;
    }

    public function getUserId() {
        return $this->userId;
    }

    public function getParameters() {
        // Return data fields as an associative array
        $paramArray = array("userId" => $this->userId,
                            "userFirstName" => $this->userFirstName,
                            "userLastName" => $this->userLastName
                           );
        return $paramArray;
    }

    public function printUser() {
        echo "<h1>SHIELD Member</h1>";
        echo "User first name: $this->userFirstName<br>";
        echo "User last name: $this->userLastName<br>";
    }

    private function initialize($formInput) {
        if (isset($formInput['userId']))
            $this->userId = $formInput['userId'];
        else 
            $this->userId = 0;
        if (isset($formInput['userFirstName']))
            $this->userFirstName = $formInput['userFirstName'];
        if (isset($formInput['userLastName']))
            $this->userLastName = $formInput['userLastName'];
    }
}
?>


//UserDB.class.php
// Responsibility: Handles all queries pertaining to comment
<?php
class UserDB {

    public static function getAll() {
        $query =  "SELECT id, first_name, last_name 
                      FROM users
                      GROUP BY id";

        $users = array();
        try {
            $db = Database::getDB ();
            $statement = $db->prepare($query);
            $statement->execute ();
            $users = UserDB::getUserArray($statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
            $statement->closeCursor ();
        } catch ( PDOException $e ) { // Not permanent error handling
            echo "<p>Error getting all users ".$e->getMessage()."</p>";
        }
        return $users;
    }

    public static function getUserArray($rowSets) {
        $users = array ();
        foreach ( $rowSets as $userRow ) {
            $user = UserDB::getUser($userRow);
            array_push ( $users, $user );
        }
        return $users;
    }


    public static function getUser($userRow) {
        return new UserData ( $userRow );
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: After `$myUsers = UserDB::getAll();`, add `var_dump($myUsers);`. What does it say?

Comment: Nothing shows up on the page. It doesn't get any errors just a blank page.

Comment: We're going to need to dig deeper. Can you post the contents of `UserDB.class.php`?

Comment: Its already there. Just scroll down to the bottom

Comment: No worries! seeing anything suspicious?

Comment: I do! I'll post an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database fieldnames do not match with what's expected in your UserData class.

Try this:

```
private function initialize($formInput) {
    if (isset($formInput['id']))
        $this->userId = $formInput['id'];
    else 
        $this->userId = 0;
    if (isset($formInput['first_name']))
        $this->userFirstName = $formInput['first_name'];
    if (isset($formInput['last_name']))
        $this->userLastName = $formInput['last_name'];
}
```

(or rename your database fields to match what you had in this class before)

Comment: Well this did help me get data out the DB but not into the view I wanted. showUsers is still blank. Makes me think there is something else wrong that Im not seeing but as far as getting data from the database yes this solved it. Thank you !